# Listbox databinding to grid or canvas

Tags: wpf, layout, listbox

i'm trying to make a "Settings" panel.  i've got a listbox, similar to the listbox on the iPad here:

[image]

i need the user to be able to add to the settings list on the left, saved into an xml file.

so, when the user selects an item in the listbox, how do i change either a grid or canvas (depending on what the user selected) and add the items to the different layout?

so if the user selects general, the layout would be a grid with some items, how do i data bind the listbox to set that up?

i'd rather not use buttons instead of a listbox, is there a better way to set this up?  like i said, i need to have the user be able to add things to the settings list.

---

i'm just programmatically creating the data template at the right going by what a user selects in the listbox

Comment: Search the internet for **Master Detail** views in WPF ... you will find lot of examples there... one such http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/03/13/master-detail-patter-implemented-using-wpf.aspx

Comment: Select from which listbox and change which layout?  There are several controls and layouts on that iPad sample.   Post what you have and a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always programmaticaly change the container of your items.

So upon selection, you can remove the concerned items from the `canvas` (just as an Example), and add them to a `grid`. 
If the grid is non existent, you will want to create the grid :)

Remember that `WPF` is based on a hierarchical organization, so you can quite easily find all the childs of a certain control (or find the parent/parents of an item)